# Deserialize multilevel JSON string with vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net, javascriptserializer

I have been trying to deserialize json string in vb.net. I am able successfully get a response using

```
            Using myResp = TryCast(myReq.GetResponse(), System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
                Using myReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(myResp.GetResponseStream())
                    responseContent = myReader.ReadToEnd()

                End Using
            End Using
```

responseContent:

```
{
    "devices": {
        "totalCount": 1,
        "totalPage": 1,
        "pageNum": 0,
        "transactions": [{
            "transactionId": "20211005200111",
            "state": "Complete",
            "type": "Put",
            "operationType": "UPLOAD",
            "devices": [{
                "imei": "357452100344123",
                "code": 40000004,
                "message": "DEVICE_INVALID",
                "data": "The specified device is not valid."
            }, {
                "imei": "357452100344409",
                "code": 40000005,
                "message": "DEVICE_DUPLICATE",
                "data": "The specified device already exists."
            }]
        }]
```

created classes to hold data:

```
    Public Class devices
            Public Property devicelist As List(Of device)
    End Class
    Public Class device
            Public Property pageNum As Integer
            Public Property totalCount As Integer
            Public Property totalPage As Integer
            Public Property transactions As List(Of transaction)
    End Class
    Public Class transaction
            Public Property transactionId As String
            Public Property state As String
            Public Property type As String
            Public Property operationType As String
            Public Property devices As List(Of mydevice)
    End Class
    Public Class mydevice
            Public Property imei As String
            Public Property code As Integer
            Public Property message As String
            Public Property data As String
    End Class
```

When I attempt to deserialize, no error is thrown however nothing gets populated:

[VB debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jenxE.png)

Please let me know what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Update your question and add the code you've used to deserialize the Json.  Also do wonder about the Json, you've got two different objects/collections in there with the same name might be causing issues with the deserialization.  Do you have any control over the source?

Comment: You're trying to deserialize into `devices` which only contains a list, but the json you show doesn't have a list at the top level, it just has a single object.  You should be deserializing into a scalar `device` rather than a list.  (If it could be a single object or it could be a list, which isn't unheard-of, I'd recommend doing a search---it's a common enough problem that there are already posted solutions for it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for my thoughts,

First of all, it looks like the Json form is wrong.
The last point }} is missing.

Second, Object is wrong.
The property name must be the same as the Json name.
If property name is different, it should be marked using JsonProperty.

I applied the contents and made a test source.

```
 Public Class root
      <JsonProperty("devices")>
      Public Property devicelist As devices
   End Class


   Public Class devices
      Public Property pageNum As Integer
      Public Property totalCount As Integer
      Public Property totalPage As Integer
      Public Property transactions As List(Of transaction)
   End Class

   Public Class transaction
         Public Property transactionId As String
         Public Property state As String
         Public Property type As String
         Public Property operationType As String
         Public Property devices As List(Of mydevice)
      End Class

      Public Class mydevice
         Public Property imei As String
         Public Property code As Integer
         Public Property message As String
         Public Property data As String
      End Class

      Private Sub test()

      Try

         Dim Json As String = "{
                               'devices': {
                                   'totalCount': 1,
                                   'totalPage': 1,
                                   'pageNum': 0,
                                   'transactions': [{
                                       'transactionId': '20211005200111',
                                       'state': 'Complete',
                                       'type': 'Put',
                                       'operationType': 'UPLOAD',
                                       'devices': [{
                                           'imei': '57452100344123',
                                           'code': 40000004,
                                           'message': 'DEVICE_INVALID',
                                           'data': 'The specified device is not valid.'
                                       }, {
                                           'imei': '357452100344409',
                                           'code': 40000005,
                                           'message': 'DEVICE_DUPLICATE',
                                           'data': 'The specified device already exists.'
                                       }]
                                   }]
                                 }}"

         Dim ds As root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of root)(Json)


         Dim d As devices = ds.devicelist

         Console.WriteLine(d.pageNum)
         Console.WriteLine(d.totalCount)
         Console.WriteLine(d.totalPage)

         For Each tran In d.transactions

            Console.WriteLine(tran.transactionId)

            For Each dd In tran.devices

               Console.WriteLine(dd.code)

            Next

         Next

      Catch ex As Exception
         MsgBox(ex.ToString)
      End Try
   End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I assumed the response from the server was complete. Will keep this in mind and check response for completeness in future.  "If the drug is different, it should be marked using JsonProperty" Thank you for sharing this. Code now works to extract IMEI.

Comment: I do not get this sorry, Where is tran and where is dd ?